# How to get the executable name or process id clicking a window

Tags: java

Is there a way to get the executable name or id of a process clicking a window? I want to do a counter that counts the time a user uses an application (game). It's only for Windows and done in java.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's your game and your code, why worry about process id or executable name? Why not just give your application a MouseListener or something similar? Also, you never mention which graphics library you are using. Is this a Swing application?

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels The application that I want to capture is not mine and I think it's not necessary to know if it's done in opengl or directx because I only want to capture the process id or name and monitorize it until it finishes.

Comment: The game is created in Java or the monitoring software is?

Comment: The monitoring software.

Comment: If it's windows only you will find it much easier to create the monitoring you're looking for in .NET. If you insist on doing it in Java then you are going to need to use JNI.